# rection of the verb "relate to"

Tags: prepositions, word-order

From [Polygon](http://www.polygon.com/2016/1/2/10700480/sherlock-the-abominable-bride-review):

> During the stakeout, Watson and Holmes are forced to sit by each other in cramped quarters, and with nothing to do until the bride shows up, actually attempt to have a personal conversation that isn't at all work related.

Why is not used the preposition "to" at the end of the above sentence: "*…that isn't at all work related to*" or "*that isn't at all related to work*". Does the verb "relate to" not belong to the same category, like for example, "hide from", "protect from", "accuse of" and so on?

Comment: This is a casual use of an adjectival compound we'd write formally as <work-related>.

Comment: you could say : *not related to work* or, *not work-related.*

Answer (score 3):

You certainly could say, "... that isn't related to work."

"Work-related" is an adjective meaning "related to work". It's normally written with the hyphen, like I showed it there. I'd say it's wrong without the hyphen; it's certainly unusual.